# Intellij not able to create Google AppEngine project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create a new Google AppEngine project, but failing. Here's my setup:

- Windows 10, x64
- Intellij Community Edition, 2016.3.3
- JDK 1.7.67 & 1.8.121
- JAVA_HOME set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67 (I also tried the 1.8 version)
- Google Cloud SDK 141 (from "gcloud info")
- Google Cloud Tools plugin in Intellij v16.11.6 - see screenshot

Despite all this I am unable to create new AppEngine project / debug existing one. In the "New Project" dialog I don't have the option for Google AppEngine (screenshot #2). As for the debugging I don't have the "AppEngine Dev" option among debuggers - I only have gradle / groovy / some others / and Google AppEngine Deployment (screenshot #3). But no option to debug locally.

Any ideas what's wrong with my setup? Anything I missed?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you need Intellij Ultimate edition
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij/issues/1200